# Using mongolab on a shared hosting site

Tags: codeigniter, mongodb, mlab

We are looking at mongolab (http://mongolab.com) to host our data (originally stored in MySQL).  We are currently using a shared hosting plan so we don't have the ability to install applications, so I'm not sure if we can use mongo at the current time.  They have a rest API but I can't tell from the documentation if we can use them without the mongo binary.

The very first action in their tutorial is to run this command:

$ bin/mongo dbh23.mongolab.com:27237/my_new_db -u  -p

So my question is, is it possible to use mongolab from a shared hosting plan? (Using CodeIgniter)

I'm sorry if this is a basic question, however I've only ever used SQL based databases ever.

Answer (score 2):

The [`mongo` shell](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/mongo+-+The+Interactive+Shell) is the default approach for database administration; you can use that from your own computer to connect to MongoLab (i.e. you do not have to run this from your web server, although that is an option).

The command line connection uses the standard [Mongo Wire Protocol](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Mongo+Wire+Protocol), which is directly supported by the MongoDB [client drivers](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Drivers) (from popular programming languages) and [Admin UIs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Admin+UIs).

Your CodeIgniter application can call the MongoLab API directly; it does not require any special binaries to be installed.

It would be very worthwhile to learn how to work with the default `mongo` shell rather than an Admin UI.

Answer (score 1):

Site5 has the drivers installed, just ask them to open the port for your connection to your mongo hosting.